# Fatest way to populate Span<int> with an integer enumeration in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, simd

I am looking for the fastest C# / .NET Core method capable of filling a `Span<int>` with the enumeration 0, 1, 2, 3, ... The naive `for` loop - see below - is already plenty fast, but there is probably an even faster SIMD option.

```
Span<int> buffer = ..; // snipped
for(var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    buffer[i] = i;
```

How to accelerate this buffer-filling method with SIMD?

Comment: Probably using an array of fixed length is faster.

Comment: Ahead-of-time C compilers can easily auto-vectorize this.  (Start with a vector of `{0,1,2,3}` and `paddd` a vector of `{4,4,4,4}`, easily extensible for wider SIMD vectors). https://godbolt.org/z/HGhErV IDK if any C# runtimes do that.

Comment: dotnet core 3 introduced hardware specific instructions ("hardware intrinsics")  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below, some optimizations attempts. The first one `Default` is the basic for loop. The second, `Batch4`, is the same but initializing 4 indexes in a single loop iteration. 4th and 5th are like 2nd but with more affectation by iteration.

The 3rd is an implementation using `System.Numerics.Vector<T>`. This datatype is known by the jit, that replace arithmetic operations by SIMD counterpart. On my machine, it's twice faster than default implementation.

The drawback here is that the buffer size must be a multiple of 4. (8/16 for `Batch16` / `Batch16`). If not, the last rows must be handle manually outside the main loop.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace bench
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Sp>();
        }
    }

    [SimpleJob]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    //[DisassemblyDiagnoser(printAsm: true, printIL: true, printSource: true, printDiff: true)]
    public class Sp
    {
        private readonly int[] spanBack = new int[100000];
        private readonly Vector<int> baseV;
        private readonly Vector<int> accV;

        public Sp()
        {
            if (spanBack.Length % Vector<int>.Count != 0) throw new Exception("Invalid array size");

            if (Vector<int>.Count == 4)
            {
                baseV = new Vector<int>(new[] { 4, 4, 4, 4 });
                accV = new Vector<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, });
            }
            else if (Vector<int>.Count == 8)
            {
                baseV = new Vector<int>(new[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 });
                accV = new Vector<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid vector size");
            }
        }
        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public int[] Default()
        {
            Span<int> buffer = spanBack.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                buffer[i] = i;

            return spanBack;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int[] Batch4()
        {
            Span<int> buffer = spanBack.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + 4)
            {
                buffer[i + 0] = i + 0;
                buffer[i + 1] = i + 1;
                buffer[i + 2] = i + 2;
                buffer[i + 3] = i + 3;
            }

            return spanBack;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int[] BatchSimd()
        {
            int batchSize = Vector<int>.Count;
            var accV = this.accV;

            Span<int> buffer = spanBack.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + batchSize)
            {
                var currentSlice = buffer.Slice(i, batchSize);

                var v = new Vector<int>(currentSlice);
                v = v + accV;
                accV = accV + baseV;

                v.CopyTo(currentSlice);
            }

            return spanBack;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int[] Batch8()
        {
            Span<int> buffer = spanBack.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + 8)
            {
                buffer[i + 0] = i + 0;
                buffer[i + 1] = i + 1;
                buffer[i + 2] = i + 2;
                buffer[i + 3] = i + 3;
                buffer[i + 4] = i + 4;
                buffer[i + 5] = i + 5;
                buffer[i + 6] = i + 6;
                buffer[i + 7] = i + 7;
            }

            return spanBack;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int[] Batch16()
        {
            Span<int> buffer = spanBack.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + 16)
            {
                buffer[i + 0] = i + 0;
                buffer[i + 1] = i + 1;
                buffer[i + 2] = i + 2;
                buffer[i + 3] = i + 3;
                buffer[i + 4] = i + 4;
                buffer[i + 5] = i + 5;
                buffer[i + 6] = i + 6;
                buffer[i + 7] = i + 7;
                buffer[i + 8] = i + 8;
                buffer[i + 9] = i + 9;
                buffer[i + 10] = i + 10;
                buffer[i + 11] = i + 11;
                buffer[i + 12] = i + 12;
                buffer[i + 13] = i + 13;
                buffer[i + 14] = i + 14;
                buffer[i + 15] = i + 15;
            }

            return spanBack;
        }
    }
}
```

Csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.12.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Result of `dotnet run -c Release`:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-2600K CPU 3.40GHz (Sandy Bridge), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.100-preview1-014459
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.50403, CoreFX 4.700.19.50410), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.50403, CoreFX 4.700.19.50410), X64 RyuJIT
```

```
|     Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|----------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|    Default | 45.55 us | 0.081 us | 0.067 us |  1.00 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|     Batch4 | 34.23 us | 0.069 us | 0.065 us |  0.75 |     - |     - |     - |       1 B |
| Batch4Simd | 22.23 us | 0.054 us | 0.051 us |  0.49 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|     Batch8 | 31.53 us | 0.160 us | 0.134 us |  0.69 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|    Batch16 | 32.10 us | 0.197 us | 0.164 us |  0.70 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
```

Edit: Suggestion from @harold

```
[Benchmark]
public int[] BatchSimd_harold()
{
    int batchSize = Vector<int>.Count;
    var accV = this.accV;

    Span<int> buffer = spanBack.AsSpan();
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + batchSize)
    {
        var currentSlice = buffer.Slice(i, batchSize);

        accV.CopyTo(currentSlice);
        accV = accV + baseV;
    }

    return spanBack;
}
```

Result :

```
|           Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|----------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|          Default | 46.08 us | 0.331 us | 0.310 us |  1.00 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|        BatchSimd | 22.37 us | 0.150 us | 0.141 us |  0.49 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
| BatchSimd_harold | 18.72 us | 0.255 us | 0.239 us |  0.41 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
```

Edit 2: bench on more recent cpu

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-6820HQ CPU 2.70GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), X64 RyuJIT
```

```
|           Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|----------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|--------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|          Default | 59.05 us | 1.169 us | 2.362 us | 59.01 us |  1.00 |    0.00 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|           Batch4 | 44.39 us | 0.865 us | 0.722 us | 44.48 us |  0.76 |    0.03 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|        BatchSimd | 15.37 us | 0.364 us | 1.049 us | 15.07 us |  0.26 |    0.02 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
| BatchSimd_harold | 11.77 us | 0.219 us | 0.205 us | 11.80 us |  0.20 |    0.01 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|           Batch8 | 43.62 us | 0.871 us | 1.838 us | 43.46 us |  0.74 |    0.04 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|          Batch16 | 42.53 us | 0.846 us | 2.317 us | 41.92 us |  0.73 |    0.05 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
```

Comment: Doesn't work on my PC, it has AVX2 so `Vector<int>` has length 8 and they go out of bounds when initialized from those arrays

Comment: Ok, not a big deal. You just need to set `batchSize` to 8 and complete `baseV4` and `accV4 ` to have 8 value. On My machine Vector<int>.Count is always 4, so couldn't test with 8.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you can share the result it will be nice.

Comment: Well, I don't have BenchmarkDotNet installed. By the way I could improve it slightly by not reading the old currentSlice into a vector, just writing to it.

Comment: You're rigth. Awesome. It's my first time with SIMD api, so maybe far from the best answer possible. But fun to do it. I'm wondering if intrinsic apis can help here too.

Comment: Intrinsics don´t give any further speedup here. Notice that the results are non-linearly dependent on the size of your data: using 100_000_000 integers makes the gain reduce from 2.4x to 1.6x on my PC (since you are out of the processor´s data cache for most of the ops).